# how to use app links to pass parameter to android playstore to be retrieved when app is installed

Tags: android, google-play, facebook-friends, applinks

I'm developing a social android trivia game.
When a user challenges to a game a friend, who doesn't have my trivia game installed, i'd like to send him a custom url to download the app from the market containing a parameter of the inviting user id.

when the app is run for the first time, i need to be able to receive the parameter passed to the market, in order to identify the user and show him the game he was challenged to.
i couldn't figure out how to do this with app links and didn't find any appropriate example.

any help would be greatly welcomed!
Thanks,
Ido

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To send data to the Android Market, you have to build an uri like this one:

```
market://details?id=my.package.name&referrer=someDataToTransfer
```

To get this data back, you should implement an `INSTALL_REFERRER` Receiver.

```
<receiver android:name="my.package.MyReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"></action>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

[Here is a short tutorial](http://n3vrax.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/listen-for-install-referrer-broadcast-message-get-referrer-on-install/) that will explain you how to fully implement this solution.

And if you want to test it without writting any code, checkout my app: `Install Referrer` on [GitHub](https://github.com/SimonMarquis/Android-InstallReferrer) or on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.simon.marquis.installreferrer)

Comment: thanks for the reply. this is a good alternative solution to app links. I've decided to implement it as I was having problems with app links

Comment: @user3241315 don't forget to upvote/validate this answer if it was the one you use ;)

Comment: thanks:) that is the method i used and it works well. Simon Marquis do you know if its possible to customize the url i pass to the market or i need to use their parameters?

Comment: Is there an equivalent for this for iOS?